# after sending email application closes and comes to home

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                        new String[] { "email@example.com" });
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject here");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body text");
                File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                // File file = new File(root, filename);
                if (!file.exists() || !file.canRead()) {
                    Toast.makeText(couponAlert, "Attachment Error",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // finish();
                    return;
                }

            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            ;
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            final PackageManager pm = couponAlert.getPackageManager();
            final List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryIntentActivities(
                    intent, 0);
            ResolveInfo best = null;
            for (final ResolveInfo info : matches)
                if (info.activityInfo.packageName.endsWith(".gm")
                        || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(
                                "gmail"))
                    best = info;
            if (best != null)
                intent.setClassName(best.activityInfo.packageName,
                        best.activityInfo.name);
            couponAlert.startActivity(intent);
            couponAlert.callFinish();
```

I want to mail through gmail,i am calling the gmail application through intent,but after sending the email,it goes to home and my application closes.
    One thing is here.the Activity from which i am calling email intent is Child activity of Tabactivity,our application is working on MainTAb activity and the email function is used in one of them activity.
please reply early

Comment: If there is a crash, please post logcat

Comment: you need to manage activity for result for this issue

Comment: how can i??i tried startactvityresult..but its  not comming in onactiivtyresult...so can i manage the result?

Comment: You are calling `couponAlert.startActivity(intent);`, Shouldn't it be `couponAlert.startActivityForResult(intent)`?

Comment: tried but not workred

Comment: its a object of activity from which i am adding another view

Comment: you start this mail service from activity or fragment?'

Comment: i think there is some problem in your current context...

Comment: can you please share your whole activity code

Comment: Yes context,I am having one maiTabActivity and it contains 4 child activty...and then this child activity are having multiple view which changes accroding to actions....nd i am using the email function in one of those view...so passing the context